# Two Sample Kolmogorov Smirnov Test SCALA Error

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, kolmogorov-smirnov

I'm trying to calculate de kolmogorov Smirnov Test in SCALA with the distribution [6,6] assuming that in the original one all the values where the same P(6) = 1. This is the way I'm trying to:

```
val data: RDD[Double] = sc.parallelize(Seq(6, 6))
val myCDF = Map(6 -> 1)
val testResult2 = Statistics.kolmogorovSmirnovTest(data, myCDF)
println(testResult2)
```

This is the error I got:

```
notebook:3: error: overloaded method value kolmogorovSmirnovTest with alternatives:   (data: org.apache.spark.api.java.JavaDoubleRDD,distName: String,params: Double*)org.apache.spark.mllib.stat.test.KolmogorovSmirnovTestResult <and>   (data: org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[Double],distName: String,params: Double*)org.apache.spark.mllib.stat.test.KolmogorovSmirnovTestResult <and>   (data: org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[Double],cdf: Double => Double)org.apache.spark.mllib.stat.test.KolmogorovSmirnovTestResult  cannot be applied to (org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[Double], scala.collection.immutable.Map[Int,Int]) val testResult2 = Statistics.kolmogorovSmirnovTest(data, myCDF)
```

Does anybody know why it doesn't work? 
Additionaly, do you Know if it is possible to do it in PySpark? Or di I have to excecute SCALA code from PySpark?
Thanks!

Comment: Does it have anything to do with pyspark?

Comment: @AndreyTyukin, I think he is using jupyter to run.

Comment: What Spark does here  ?

Comment: It is running over a Spark VM of Databricks.